# How to debug a foxpo app

Tags: debugging, foxpro

Hi I am a complete novice with fox pro, I purchased a fox pro app someyears ago and now its nolonger supported by the author so I am trying to find out the reason why it not parsing all the XML elements even though they are in the database I would like to learn as this product could be made better by completing some of code for instance the coder has no tab order to control the user imputs, I have the access to the code and I think the error lies in the implementation of the wwutils.prg, I thought rebulding the project would allow me to set break points in the modal file so that I could see the values stored I have watched a good tutorial by Garfield Hudson but I am still stuck as I need to identify the main programe I think its the one in Bold letters but I can not get this to run without errors  any help or  suggestion would be greatfully accepted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlikely the problem is in wwUtils since that's a 3rd party library, provided by Rick Strahl (www.west-wind.com), and in use by hundreds, maybe thousands of applications.

Yes, the main program is the one listed in bold.

To learn how to use the VFP Debugger, check out my paper:

http://www.tomorrowssolutionsllc.com/Conference%20Sessions/Using%20the%20Visual%20FoxPro%20Debugger%20Effectively.pdf

Tamar

Comment: Thank you Tamar, I have been playing with this app for a while to learn the IDE , I figured out that the main app set the enviroment so I have changed these to match the location where the file are now stored rather than where they would be at runtime, and so far I have got the app running in the IDE. I can start to debug it can you suggest where I might set break points on, as I can see referance to a file called MODAL1 that changes as the program progresses. I am trying to figure out why a value that is stored in the data base is not being populated in the XML file generated by the app

Comment: Just thought i'd mention I have downloaded your paper I'll print it of tommorow so I can read it thoroughly thank you once again for your help

Comment: Hi Tanar I seem to be struggling with setting up the evironment for this app I made changes to the main app and used SET PATH TO all the directorys the app uses but it seem as if the SET DEFAULT and SET PATH are lost when the I run the main.prg any ideas how I get arround this

Comment: Answered about set up on your new question.